# Cloning hard drive using the dd utility

Tags: linux, ssd, dd

I'm researching for the possible problems when cloning existing hard drive using the dd clone utility into the new hard drive.
I'm interested to know if any one is aware of unexpected behavior (or maybe experienced problems trying to execute similar task) with aligning into the ATA 4 KiB sectors. 
I will be cloning existing hard drive into the new (bigger drive) using dd and then will use gparted to expand the target drive.
Am I correct in thinking that gparted should allign the drive automatically?
Any insights will be much appreciated, Tomek

Comment: Why would you make things more complicated by using dd?

Comment: Do you have any suggestions which command (approach) will deliver the best result?

Comment: I would use `tar` to copy filesystem contents to new drive and then install boot loader on the new drive.

Comment: If you're trying to get all of the partitions then `dd` should be fine.  Increase the blocksize for more reasonable performance.

Comment: I usually do as @TeroKilkanen says....no need to worry about the underlying physical infra structure.

Answer (score 1):

If you use `dd` and your current disk is GPT-partitioned, the secondary (Backup) partition table which should at LBA-34 to LBA-1 (assuming 512-sector size) of your current disk will not be on the last 34 sectors of your new larger disk.